# как обратится к блоку внутри блока?

Tags: html, css

всем доброго времени суток
Например, есть такой код: мне нужно обратится к 2 последним элементам h4, как я могу это сделать правильно?

```html
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А в каком месте и с помощью чего нужно обратиться к этим элементам? JS, PHP, jQuery, CSS?

Comment: css, нужно обратится к 2 последним h4

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы стили применялись не ко всему блоку целиком, а только к h4, следует css исправить, например, так:

```css
.block__column:nth-last-child(-n+2) .block__item h4 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">567567
    <div class="block__item">123
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При этом, если структура блоков будет разной, то такой css не сработает. В html добавил цифры, чтобы было ясно, стиль применяется именно к h4.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы обратиться к двум последним элементам вы можете использовать псевдокласс `:nth-last-child`

`-n+2` - находит два последних элемента

Посмотрите мой пример.

```css
.block__column:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__column">
      <div class="block__item">
          <h4>Текст</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
      <div class="block__item">
          <h4>Текст</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
      <div class="block__item">
          <h4>Текст</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
      <div class="block__item">
          <h4>Текст</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно использовать свойство [`nth-last-child(m)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child), который будет принимать `m` последних элементов.

P.S. Почему-то работает только при `block__column`, хотя, если взять `h4` напрямую либо `block__item`, срабатывают ВСЕ элементы. Знать бы ещё, почему... =/

```css
.block__column:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__body">
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block__column">
    <div class="block__item">
      <h4>Текст</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: c block__item и h4 не отработает из за того что не соседние элементы (не на одном уровне)